# ¿Se puede agregar una imagen de header con wkhtmltopdf en Django?

Tags: django, pdf

me preguntaba si puedo poner hacer si puedo poner una imagen de `header` o `footer` con `pdfkit` y `wkhtmltopdf`.

```
options = {
    '--page-size': 'Letter',
    '--no-outline': None,
    '--quiet': '',
    '--header-center':'Escribir texto',
    '--footer-center': 'Escribir texto',
}
```

Se que de ésta manera se puede colocar el `header` y el `footer`, pero no sabría cómo hacer para mostrar una imagen en alguna de ellas. Tal vez alguno de vosotros me puede ayudar. De antemano, muchas gracias!